# Coalescent theory - Why are coalescent times independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, biology

I am reading from [this book](http://www.amazon.ca/Biologists-Mathematical-Modeling-Ecology-Evolution/dp/0691123446) and I want to make sure I understand what is going on.

---

**What I get from the book**

Consider a population of $N$ individuals. The population size ($N$) is constant. select two individuals randomly in the population and ask the question, when did the most recent common ancestor (MRCA) lived? Let's denote this time to the MRCA by the random variable $T_2$. Whenever, looking backward in time, we see two individuals having a common ancestor, then we refer to this event as an event of coalescence. In other words, $T_2$ is the random variable of the time (in generations) for coalescence to occur between two randomly chosen individuals in a population of constant size $N$.

The probability of not coalescing in the previous generations (that is the probability that the two randomly sampled individuals are not siblings) is $1-\frac{1}{N}$ and the probability of coalescing (probability of being siblings) is $\frac{1}{N}$. The probability of the coalescence event to occur $t$ generations ago is the probability of not coalescing for $t-1$ generations and coalescing then. Therefore $T$ has the distribution

$P(T_2=t) = \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{t-1}\frac{1}{N}$

More generally, let's denote $M_n$ the time for $n$ individuals to coalesce. If $T_n$ is the time until $n$ individuals coalesce into $n-1$ individuals (the time for one pair of individuals among $n$ individuals to coalesce), then $$M_n = \sum_{i=2}^n T_i$$

**Question**

I think that $M_n = \sum_{i=2}^n T_i$ is true only if all $T_i$ are independent variables. Are they independent? Why?

Comment: Yes. This is the Markov property of the sequence of *sets* of ancestors of the n individuals chosen at the present time.

Comment: The question seems not attractive enough to be answered. Could you suggest a source where I could learn why the $T_i$ are independent random variables? Thank you

Comment: My guess is that roughly any introduction to the coalescent would do, say Tavaré's lectures at Saint-Flour's summer school a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

After 8 years, here is an attempt to answer the question...

Let $n$ be the sample size and $N$ the population size. Consider a process $(X_t^{N,n})_{t\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ that keeps track of the individuals that have coalesced into a common ancestor going back t generations ago. This process is commonly referred as the ancestral process and it takes values in the space of partitions of the finite set ${1,\cdots,n}$.

For example, if n=3, the state space of $X^{N,n}$ is $\{ \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}, \{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}, \{\{1,3\},\{2\}\}, \{\{2,3\},\{1\}\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$, where $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ corresponds to no coalescence event taking place, $\{\{1,3\},\{2\}\}$ corresponds to the first and third sampled individuals coalescing and so on. Notice that from $\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}, \{\{1,3\},\{2\}\}$ and $\{\{2,3\},\{1\}\}$ we can only transition to $\{1,2,3\}$, and more generally, the process $X^{N,n}$ transitions to partitions that can be constructed from existing ones by merging blocks (partition elements from a given partition) together.

This defines a Markov process and it should be enough to answer your question. An interesting read would be a paper of J. F. C. Kingman, titled "On the Genealogy of Large Populations". In that setting, $M_n$ is the time for absorption for the process $X^{N,n}$.